# Switch to newlib-nano causes application to stop running

Tags: c, gcc, newlib

I have a newlib 4.9.3 2014q4 application that runs fine on my Cortex-M4 platform.  All output to the serial console uses either `iprintf` or a custom `send_str` functions.  The `send_str` is just writing bytes to the serial peripheral tx buffer (looping call to my `fputc`).

```
int _write(int fd, char *buf, int nbytes)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nbytes; i++) {
        if (*(buf + i) == '\n') {
            /* fd is incorrectly passed as arguments, as FILE is not used, but needed for build */
            fputc('\r', (FILE *) & fd);
        }
        /* fd is incorrectly passed as arguments, as FILE is not used, but needed for build */
        fputc(*(buf + i), (FILE *) & fd);
    }

    return nbytes;
}

int fputc(int ch, FILE * f)
{
    unsigned char tempch = ch;

    sendchar(&tempch);

    return ch;
}

void send_str(unsigned char* buff)
{

    while(*buff != 0){
        sendchar(buff);
        buff++;
    }
}
```

In my application's main (after init of data relocation and bss zero'ing) I print a banner.  When I use newlib-nano(`--specs=nano.specs`) this works if I use `send_str`, but not if I use `iprintf`.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[] = "Hello from Cortex-M4!\n";

    init_uart((void*)UART2_BASE_PTR, 115200);
    send_str(str);
}
```

versus

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    char str[] = "Hello from Cortex-M4!\n";

    init_uart((void*)UART2_BASE_PTR, 115200);
    iprintf("%s", str);
}
```

Using just newlib (not nano) both functions work.

Everything I've been reading suggests that changes to my application should not be required to swap between the two.  Is there an exception to this?